# different linetypes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame, and I want to plot one of the lines as solid and black (say, when diff=0.3) and all the others as dashed lines. I also want the legend can represent that. Can someone tell me how to do that? Thanks[image]

```
df <- data.frame(delta=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                 Pct=c(0.676,0.268,0.08,0.008,0,0,0.58,0.266,0.088,0.026,0.002,0,0.672,0.262,0.082,0.036,0.004,0,0.642,0.264,0.122,0.02,0.006,0),
                 diff = as.character(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)))

df$Pct=as.numeric(df$Pct)
df$delta=as.numeric(df$delta)
df$diff=as.character(df$diff)

p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = delta, y = Pct, col = diff))+
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(data=df, se=F, span=2,na.rm = TRUE) + 
  labs(title = "title", x="x axis",y="y axis")+
  scale_color_manual(name="percentage",
                     breaks=as.character(seq(0.1,0.4,0.1)), labels=as.character(seq(0.1,0.4,0.1)),
                     values=c("red","blue","black","pink")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), limits = c(0, 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = delta, limits = c(min(delta),max(delta)))

#+ geom_smooth(data=B,se=F,span=2,linetype=1,col=1)

p2 <- grid.arrange(p,bottom=textGrob("subtitle",x=0.65,y=1,gp=gpar(fontsize=9)))
```

This is when I added `linetype=diff==0.3` in aes(), but still doesn't work...

Comment: I suggest looking at `?scale_linetype_manual()` and `?scale_linetype_identity()`

Comment: I actually did. I added another variable linetype and used 
``` scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,2,1,2))``` but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have `linetype = diff` or `linetype = diff == 0.3` inside your `aes()`? That's what would map it to an aesthetic which you could control with the functions above.

Comment: I added the new plot in the post, still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = delta, y = Pct, col = diff, linetype = diff))+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(se=F, span=2,na.rm = TRUE, size = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="percentage",
                     breaks=as.character(seq(0.1,0.4,0.1)), labels=as.character(seq(0.1,0.4,0.1)),
                     values=c("red","blue","black","pink")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "percentage",
                        breaks=as.character(seq(0.1,0.4,0.1)), 
                        labels=as.character(seq(0.1,0.4,0.1)),
                        values=c("dashed", "dashed", "solid", "dashed"))
```

I combined the color and linetype legend by giving them the same name, but in this case the default formatting makes it hard to see in the legend that three of the lines are dashed. You could make the legend key larger, or use something like  `guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.2)))`, which  makes the legend lines small enough to see their various linetypes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let p be your other plot layers. You can use `geom_line(x)` and define x as any of the following values:

0 = blank

1 = solid

2 = dashed

3 = dotted

4 = dotdash

5 = longdash

6 = twodash

Instead of using a number, you can also define `linetype` by using their corresponding name. For example:

```
p + geom_line(linetype = "dashed")
```